# Interact with multiple tables using single query in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select data from multiple tables at once using a single query. I sent an Id as classify data. What I'm currently doing is writing multiple select queries to get data. I want to know if there is a way to get all data using 1 query.

What I'm doing currently E.g

```
let data = [];
query1 = SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ID = 1;
data.push(query1FetchedData);

query2 = SELECT * FROM TABLE_2 WHERE ID = 1;
data.push(query2FetchedData);

query3 = SELECT * FROM TABLE_3 WHERE ID = 1;
data.push(query3FetchedData);

query4 = SELECT * FROM TABLE_4 WHERE ID = 1;
data.push(query4FetchedData);

return data;
```

I want to know is is there a way I can fetch all using 1 query.

Sample Query will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried union?

Comment: Are the four tables related? In particular is the `id`  field in each related?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver all 4 four tables are created and have same ID, you can consider it as coming from frontend to fetch data of 1 customer from 4 different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested and assumes all the tables have a rows for all ids:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM
   table_1 AS t1 
JOIN
   table_2 AS t2
ON 
   t1.id = t2.id
JOIN 
   table_3 AS t3
ON 
   t1.id = t3.id
JOIN
   table_4 AS t4 
ON 
   t1.id = t4.id;
```